# Query latest sequence in each schedule

Tags: sql

I have a table that consists of potentially multiple sequences to each schedules.  I would like to output a single (latest) record from each sequence.  Below is an example of the table, and the output I'm looking for:

Table sample:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

The table name is dataschedule - could you let me know how to best write the sql query to get this data?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . if you want the latest sequence, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.sequence = (select max(t2.sequence)
                    from t t2
                    where t2.schedule = t.schedule and t2.id = t.id
                   );
```

In most databases, this has quite good performance with an index on `(id, schedule, sequence)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, i havent tested it as you dint provide the insert and create table scripts. Just replace table_name by you table name.

```
select table_name.*
from table_name, (select ID,schedule,max(sequence) from table_name group by ID,schedule) a
where 
table_name.ID = a.ID and 
table_name.schedule = a.schedule ;
```